# Show datetime in symfony form but store unixtime

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'have this fields on my enity to store two dates in unixtime format

```
 /**
     * @var \int
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="activation_date", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $activationDate;

    /**
     * @var \int
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="deactivation_date", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deactivationDate;
```

but in the formtype class are those fields are setted as Datetime in order to show  a date field to the user

```
->add('activation_date', DateTimeType::class, [
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'font-weight-bold'
                ],
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('deactivation_date', DateTimeType::class, [
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'font-weight-bold'
                ],
                'required' => false,
            ])
```

and the fields are shown in the view this way

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_row(form.title) }}
 {{ form_row(form.description) }}
 {{ form_row(form.activation_date) }}
 {{ form_row(form.deactivation_date) }}
 {{ form_row(form.active) }}
```

this code not work because the entity receives datetime and expects int values, how  can I store unixtime values on the database but show datetime fields in the form for create and edit??

Comment: Look into [DataTransformers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) and [`DateTimeToTimestampTransformer`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToTimestampTransformer.php) in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Set field option `input` to `timestamp`. Like this:

```php
->add('activation_date', DateTimeType::class, [
    'label_attr' => [
        'class' => 'font-weight-bold'
    ],
    'required' => false,
    'input' => 'timestamp'
])
->add('deactivation_date', DateTimeType::class, [
    'label_attr' => [
        'class' => 'font-weight-bold'
    ],
    'required' => false,
    'input' => 'timestamp'
])
```

Comment: I get this messeage `Unable to transform data for property path "activation_date": Expected a numeric.`

Comment: Please show your getters and setters on the entity.